# in javascript can i create a reference(like pointer in C) for a json value

Tags: javascript, reference

For example:
I have

```
var layout = {
    "cursor":{"left": 0, "top":0}
}
```

and I want to do something like

```
var curX = layout.cursor.left;
```

and when use alias curX and change the value of curX, the value left in cursor also change?

Or further more,

have a reference to the cursor, like

```
nodes = [
    {name: 1, children: referenceTo2}
    {name: 2, children:　null}
]
```

in that case, when we change node[1], the value in children of node[0] will change too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no JSON in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If `children` is an Object (such as your `cursor`), it's held by reference, so you can just reference it like so:

```
var cursor = { left:0, top:0 };

var nodes = [
    { name: 1, children: cursor },
    { name: 2, children: cursor }
];

nodes[0].children.left = 10;
nodes[1].children.left; //is 10
```

But if children is a String, then that's a primitive and you're a bit out of luck. You could do some fanciness with setters and ES5, but that's probably overkill for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create a reference to a value. JavaScript objects are reference types, so you can take a reference to `layout.cursor`, but you can't take a reference to `layout.cursor.left`.

Comment: @ Anthony:thanks. your answer cleared a lot of my confusion  :)